# Guardar un Array de PHP en Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy guardando un Array (`$Sucursal`) de **PHP** en mi base de datos pero al enviarlo a la Tabla de la base de datos se guarda como Array y al traerla y querer usar un `var_dump` solo dice que es Array, claro que antes de enviarla si me salen los datos como Array

Lo estoy Guardando de la siguiente Forma:

```
    //Usuario Logeado Datos//
    $ConsultaSQL = "SELECT * FROM owner WHERE owner_email='$email' ";
    $EjecutarConsulta = mysqli_query($con,$ConsultaSQL);
    $respuesta = mysqli_fetch_array($EjecutarConsulta);

    $ID_Consultado = $respuesta['owner_id'];
    $Correo = $respuesta['owner_email'];

    // Usuario Logeado Datos //

    $Sucursal = $_POST['id'];

    //var_dump($Sucursal);

    $NombreBono = $_POST['NombreBono'];
    $Monto = $_POST['Monto'];
    $Comentarios = $_POST['Comentarios'];
    $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

     if (empty($NombreBono)) 
     {

     }
     else{
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
         echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal.fire("Bono añadido correctamente","Hecho!","Realizado");';
         echo '}, 500);</script>';
     $ejecucion = "INSERT INTO `Bonos_Creados` (`NombreBono`, `Monto`, `id_QueinCreo`, `QuienCreo` ,`Fecha`, `Comentario`,`RegionesDisponibles`) VALUES ('$NombreBono', '$Monto', '$ID_Consultado', '$Correo', '$fecha', '$Comentarios','$Sucursal')";
     $validacion = mysqli_query($con,$ejecucion);
     //echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
     }
```

y esta es la parte del HTML (no tengo problema con este pero por si les es de ayuda)

```
//Consulta de las Regiones Disponibles//
$ConsultaRegiones = "SELECT * FROM regiones";
$EjecutarConsultaRegiones = mysqli_query($con,$ConsultaRegiones);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($EjecutarConsultaRegiones)){

echo'<label><input type="checkbox" name="id['.$row['id'].']"  id="cbox1" value="'. $row['nombre'].'"> '. $row['nombre'].' </label><br>';

//echo'<label>'. $row['nombre'].'</label>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como dicen [aquí](https://sebhastian.com/mysql-array/):

> Although an array is one of the most common data types in the world of
> programming, MySQL actually doesn't support saving an array type
> directly. You can't create a table column of array type in MySQL. The
> easiest way store array type data in MySQL is to use the JSON data
> type.

Que traducido sería:

> Aunque una matriz es uno de los tipos de datos más comunes en el mundo
> de la programación, MySQL en realidad no admite guardar un tipo de
> matriz directamente. No puede crear una columna de tabla de tipo
> matriz en MySQL. La forma más fácil para almacenar datos de tipo matriz
> en MySQL es usar el tipo de datos JSON.

Por lo tanto, para almacenar un **array** puedes convertirlo a `json` mediante `json_encode($array)` ([documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)) y almacenarlo de ese modo, y cuando extraigas el dato lo conviertes de nuevo a `array` mediante `json_decode($json_de_la_base_de_datos)` ([documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)).

Del mismo modo, también es frecuente, aunque ya no tan moderno ni tan extendido como **json**, usar las funciones de [`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.serialize.php)/[`unserialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unserialize.php) para almacenar arrays de datos en modo texto serializados.

Actualmente **mysql** soporta directamente el tipo `json`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]